# Why is my viewController background color permanently white?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, background-color, hierarchy

If I change the `background color` and run the app the color works fine, but as soon as I add `subViews` like a `tableView` or a `containerView` the still visible parts of the background becomes white.

I have tried:
- To set the color programatically. Still white.
- To add another `UIView` on the `superView`, add the `subViews` to that and changed the `color` on the `UIView` instead. Still white.
- While on the same approach as above, changed the `superView` color and set the `UIView` `color` to clear. Still white.
- Changed the `alpha value` to 0, but this makes the `subViews` invisible as well.

This is the hierarchy:

[image]

Have never run into this problem before and I don't understand it...

Comment: it would be better if you named the nested view instead of having to views called just 'View'

Comment: I would suggest either removing the nested view or setting it's color to clear and all it's content then set the color to only the root view

Comment: Try removing your subview and then set the colour through storyboard and see if the changes is reflected in view controller before run and if so then run the code n check.
If still gives white then make it programmatically once again and check.
e.g: self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

Comment: if it's a tableview have you tried nil out the backgroundView?. i.e. `tableview.backgroundView = nil`

Comment: I did try setting it to clear with a color on the root view, but still white. I tried removing the subView and set the root color, but still white. I have also tried programatically. The tableView doesn't cover the entire background anyway so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Have you tried running your app in [Debug View Hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html) mode to verify what view exactly is causing the visible white areas?

Comment: @Gamma, good idea. Even though I have changed the root to another color it still shows as white in debug mode. I have checked the code and there is nothing that put it to white... :(

Answer (score 0):

Check every outlet in storyborad if it has a background color of white . Or self.view.backgroundcolor to clearcolor may work , There must be a view under the view which color is white. Or sometimes there needs time to load the storyboard and this causes some undefined behaviour.You can try a dispatch_time_after in viewdidLoad and then start your code from there.